# mysql UPDATE with php column1 SET = array[0][0]?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, where-clause

I'm having a problem with updating a value in a column in my database. I can get it to work if i use

> $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Customers SET NextExpectedCut = 222 WHERE Name = 'ruth'");

But I entered all the databases information into an array ($rows).. so there for I tested already by doing:

```
echo $rows[0][0];
```

And i get the first customers name on the browser so why cant I get this to work? Am I formatting it wrong or is there a different way to do this?

```
if(isset($_GET['test']) && $_GET['test'] =="1")
{
   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Customers");

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
      $rows[]=$row;

   }

echo $rows[0][0] ." is finished";

$result1= mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Customers SET NextExpectedCut = 222 WHERE Name = $rows[0][0]");
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to denote your array with brackets and quote your input:

```
$result1= mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Customers SET NextExpectedCut = 222 WHERE Name = '{$rows[0][0]}'");
```

or concatenate your string

```
$result1= mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Customers SET NextExpectedCut = 222 WHERE Name = '".$rows[0][0]."'");
```

You may wish to use a prepared statement instead of a generated query instead: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php.  Prepared statements are generally safer than generated queries.